# How to get Screenshot of WPF Webrowser Control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to get a **screenshot** of the page which downloads WPF Webrowser Control  on fly in memory.

*The basic requirement is the WPF Webrowser is hidden or even doesn't implemented in XAML.*

Is it possible to do? If yes then how?

**-------- DRAFT SOLUTION -----------**

```
var topLeftCorner = MainBrowser.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
var topLeftGdiPoint = new System.Drawing.Point((int)topLeftCorner.X, (int)topLeftCorner.Y);
var size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)MainBrowser.ActualWidth, (int)MainBrowser.ActualHeight);

Bitmap screenShot = new Bitmap((int)MainBrowser.ActualWidth, (int)MainBrowser.ActualHeight);

using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenShot))
{
   graphics.CopyFromScreen(topLeftGdiPoint, new System.Drawing.Point(),
        size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}

screenShot.Save(@"D:\Temp\screenshot.png");
```

Comment: Just a random idea, I wonder if is going to work if display the WebBrowser but out of the screen lol. (I don't know how to do it, but I would like to know how too)

Comment: Hidden / Collapsed elements cannot be copied as graphics into the clipboard memory... your screen video buffer havent rendered it so how do you expect it to be copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an idea you can use a virtual printer installed on your PC and print as image.

```
PrintDialog p = new PrintDialog();
p.PrintVisual(webBrowser1,"webBrowser1");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var topLeftCorner = MainBrowser.PointToScreen(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0));
var topLeftGdiPoint = new System.Drawing.Point((int)topLeftCorner.X, (int)topLeftCorner.Y);
var size = new System.Drawing.Size((int)MainBrowser.ActualWidth, (int)MainBrowser.ActualHeight);
Bitmap screenShot = new Bitmap((int)MainBrowser.ActualWidth, (int)MainBrowser.ActualHeight);
using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(screenShot))
{
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(topLeftGdiPoint, new System.Drawing.Point(), size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
}
screenShot.Save(@"D:\Temp\screenshot.png");
```